# How to validate CSV column count when decoding to Scala case class using Kantan CSV

Tags: scala, csv, parsing

I am using the Kantan CSV library - https://nrinaudo.github.io/kantan.csv/ - to decode CSV into a collection of case classes. The code fragment is as follows:

```
case class Journey(origin: String, destination: String)
val file = ??? // read file
val xs: Either[ReadError, List[Journey]] = ReadResult.sequence(file.readCsv[List, Journey](rfc.withHeader))
```

Question is: How can I enforce strict parsing so that should the CSV contain any row that does not have 2 fields, an error will be raised and returned (as ReadError)

Answer (score 0):

This is probably long stale, but non the less: If I get you right, you want to throw an exception of some kind when encountering a ReadError? This defeats the purpose of functional programming where you don't throw exceptions from any function, but declare what can go wrong in the function's return type - hence the `Either[ReadError, List[Journey]]`.

If you don't really care for the error itself you could "flatten" this into a Sequence of Options like so:

```
new File(filePath).readCsv[List, Journey](rfc.withHeader).map {
            case Left(_) => None
            case Right(value) => Option(value)
        }
```

Yet I'm not sure if that is what you want and you loose information on the way. But this way you'd have a List of `None` where an error occurred and an `Option[Journey]` in any other case, over which you could map pretty comfortably.

Comment: Hi @Aarkon, thanks for your answer. It's been a while, but I think the issue I was facing is that I wanted the last statement to always compute functionally (i.e. either a valid result or ReadError otherwise). If my memory serves me right, there were some scenarios where the API explicitly threw an exception despite the functional nature of the method signature. It might very well have been a limitation of the library, or that the use (as shown in the question) is incorrect.

Comment: Ah, OK, I see! There are indeed cases where even in functional code you might want to throw exceptions, though this should then happen in the context of a monad if I've got my theory right.  I'm not sure if it was Kantan, but there was a CSV library for Scala where the author stated that while the interface to the lib encourages a purely functional style, the inner workings fell back to imperative code where really needed.